# Whom does one save first?

Tags: halacha, vehicles-transportation, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, current-events

As a follow up to the controversy regarding the [Costa Concordia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Costa_Concordia)

---

1. If a ship is in danger of sinking, is the captain allowed to save himself first, or must he be the last man off the ship?
2. Do the men have to save the women and children first, or is it first come first served to the rescue boats?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on sources and discussion [here](http://torahmusings.com/2012/01/evacuating-a-sinking-ship/) it seems that Rav Moshe Feinstein would hold that everyone should line up by the life boats and be saved in that order (independent of age and gender).

Comment: He doesn't seem to discuss the captain issue.