# Does a Rabbi have to sink with his ship?

Tags: history, rabbis, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, holocaust-shoah

There is a famous story (mentioned in his [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elchonon_Wasserman#Rabbi_Wasserman_visits_America) article) that R' Elchonon Wasserman visited the United States before the war. He had the option to stay, but he refused since (as I heard) "A leader doesn't abandon his flock".

He went back to Lithuania and was killed by the Nazis during the Holocaust with his students.

---

Even though one could say that he didn't know how bad the Holocaust would be, he undoubtedly knew that his life would be in greater danger in Europe than in America.

Given the principle that "Chayecha Kodmin" - one must save one's life before someone else's (and even more so here, that he wouldn't be able to do anything in Lithuania to save his students), what Halachik right did he have to go back to Europe?

Comment: +1 Had this questions recently...besides the fact that he could have opened new Yeshivot in America and spread more Torah.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22515/759

Comment: There are lots of similar examples to this, each nuanced in different ways. For example, Rachel Citron, the daughter of R' Yosef Rosen (the Rogatchover), left Petach Tikva for Dvinsk to work with her father's student, publishing his various manuscripts. They worked until the Nazi ban on Jewish publications reached them, at which point they worked covertly. They worked right up until the point when they were murdered, making available to the world the Rogatchover's manuscripts: http://www.tzafnat.com/mission--history.html

Comment: we see moshe rabeinu said "erase me from Your book if You dont forgive them" (for the golden calf). could be he learned it from there

Comment: Dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13807/whom-does-one-save-first

Comment: @DoubleAA not necessarily. Even if the captain should wait, who says he should go from land back on to the ship?

Comment: @good_ole_ray that could depend on http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28982/can-you-ask-god-to-kill-you

Comment: Also on topic: http://www.tabletmag.com/jewish-life-and-religion/137000/costa-concordia-captain-ship/2

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its a question of chiyuv (obligation) but more of a moral feeling towards his students. When they heard that he is coming back they were probably inspired and rejuvenated etc.
Which could of enabled his students to continue life.
in addition noone really knew the real situation in Europe then.

Comment: rosh mishpacha, welcome to Mi Yodeya. I don't see that this answers the question, which asks for an halachic basis for _Rav Elchanan_'s actions. Unless you can [provide](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/30075/edit) halachic grounds for what you called his "moral feeling", or the halachic relevance of "noone really knew..."?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin I'm not sure what your point is. He though it was correct to go back. Why does he need a formal halachik chiyuv?

Comment: @msh210: The halachic relevance of "noone really knew" is fairly obvious; the obligation to save oneself can only be said to take effect when and if your life is in clear and present danger. Since he did not know what the situation was, there can be no chiyuv to stay away.

Furthermore, there is an argument to be made that he had a chiyuv to return to lead his flock, as he was their spiritual leader, without whom the flock would be like the people in the desert; without water, i.e. Torah.

Comment: Is there a halachic teaching that we shall make an account of ourselves to Hashem? If that is the case, then it becomes a question of which course of action one would prefer to be discussed at that time.