# Who is pulled to safety first?

Tags: halacha, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, choleh-sick, current-events

If a group of people are in mortal danger, all of the same gender (cf. [Horayot 13a](https://www.sefaria.org/Horayot.13a.8?with=all&lang=bi); some suggest that the Mishnah on Horayot is not discussing a case of rescuing from physical danger, cf. [Tziz Eliezer vol. 18 §1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14517&st=&pgnum=14)) and age group, and are not all able to be rescued simultaneously, accordingly to the *Halachah* how is it determined who to rescue first?

An example of such a situation, and the decision that inspired this question, is the current situation of the young Thai soccer team who are submerged in a maze of caves filled with water with escalating water levels and decreasing oxygen supply. Media outlets reported that the governor of [Chiang Rai](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiang_Rai) ordered that the healthier players will be rescued first.

According to [this](https://www.jdn.co.il/beit_hamidrash/803803) essay, it would seem that [R. Eliashiv](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yosef_Shalom_Eliashiv) would instruct that a lottery be drawn in such a situation. From a responsum of [R. Feinstein](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Feinstein) ([Iggros Moshe vol. 7, CM §73:2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=921&st=&pgnum=301)) it would seem that the individuals who have a higher chance of living should be rescued first. However, in our particular case, at least in our hypothetical, none of the members are terminally ill.

Related: partial reasoning of R. Feinstein's opinion on [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29507/15571) case

Related: [a broader question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13807/15571)

Comment: Your "According…" paragraph sounds like it should be an answer post rather than in the question.

Comment: I'm looking for a more sourced and thorough answer, which that cited essay falls short of. (Even R. Feinstein's resp., which isn't entirely comparable, is mainly m'svara d'nafshe.)

Comment: @Oliver -  In this case there were at least two more factors to consider. 1 -There was also a danger in the evacuation itself. 2 - There was a chance to strengthen the boys left behind and lower their risk.  Would this change the comparison to Rav Elyashiv and Rav Moshe?

Comment: @פריזהב 1. Not sure how this would affect our essential question; it's related to a question about putting oneself in danger to save other/s. 2. Indeed, that's part of why I don't think those opinions are comparable.

Comment: Who's one to decide? If the boys - everyone rightfully claims my life first! If the crew - they have no way of properly evaluating them.

Comment: @AlBerko I intentionally didn't include the perspective of the imperiled, that can be a separate question - see toward the end of the ref. Tzitz Eliezer quoting Sefer Hasidim and Yerushalmi. Re. your second point, the Torah (and by extension, Chazal) had a pretty good moral sense, so I'm wondering what the halachah would be even if throwing a lottery is the answer.

Comment: Let's just be thankful that all the people in the cave were rescued, and send up a prayer for the guy who died trying to save them.

Answer (score -1):

I"m surprised that you didn't quote the end of that Mishna in Horayot 13a that a Talmid Chacham comes before an Am Haaretz... I would therefore pasken that they shall see who of them has the most knowledge of Torah he should be saved first etc. I must add that someone with more knowledge comes before the one who is more sharp (see end of horayot סיני ועוקר הרים סיני קודם). Reminding me that I"ve always wanted to open a community where one may only live in it if he is a Baki in the entire Shas! PLZ comment if you're intrested in working with me on this project!

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Seemingly, the question was what to do after we exhaust the formal rules of precedence like this.

Comment: I was wondering, if there is a good way in times of distress where time is limited to be able to determine the levels of each of them in their learning.

Comment: @shayachagigah That sounds like a terrible community of elitists who don't recognize the intrinsic value of a Jew. Not only that, but they would be neglecting their obligation to teach others by example.